# PHP-Java-Bridge , usage of extend?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge, py4j

Java:

```
package test;

public class HelloWorld {
public HelloWorld(String args){
}

public void ppp(){
    System.out.println("....");
};

public  void set(HelloWorld hw){
    hw.ppp();
}

public static final String JAVABRIDGE_PORT = "28080";
static final php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner runner = php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner
        .getInstance(JAVABRIDGE_PORT);

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    runner.waitFor();
}
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once("/home/gt/workspace/JavaPhp/Java.inc");
use test\HelloWorld;

class abc extends HelloWorld{
function ppp(){
echo "!!!!";
}
}

$hw =new java("test.HelloWorld","str");
$hw -> set(new abc("str"));
```

You can see in the PHP code a php class extend Java class and the `set()` method is Java's methods which let PHP class pass to the Java side.

**Could it print "!!!!" not "...." ?**

I know py4j could do it , wondering how PHP/Java Bridge do it?

Comment: http://blog.csdn.net/guotong1988/article/details/51251396

Answer (score 0):

you can implement it using a custom php5/php7 __autoload function which checks each argument and, if it is an instanceof Java, wraps it using java_closure() with a list of generated interfaces for the wrapped Java type. In pseudo-code something like:

```
java_autoload_function() {...
__call(java_closure($type, null, $Class->getInterfaces($type)))
}
```

Needs not more than ~10-15 lines of additinal PHP code in Java.inc.